# Why would a PHP app be generating intermittent segfaults?

Tags: php, symfony, apache2

I'm doing some load testing on a PHP app (it's a symfony app, if that matters), and the logs are full of errors like these. I'm struggling to work out why these segfaults are occurring.

> [Wed Mar 13 00:54:47 2013] [notice] child pid 18830 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
>
> [Wed Mar 13 00:54:55 2013] [notice] child pid 19016 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
>
> [Wed Mar 13 00:54:56 2013] [notice] child pid 19002 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
>
> [Wed Mar 13 00:54:58 2013] [notice] child pid 19041 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump

When I generate a backtrace from the core dumps I get

> [New LWP 588] [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] Using host
> libthread_db library
>
> "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tls/i686/nosegneg/libthread_db.so.1". Core was
> generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start'. Program terminated with
> signal 7, Bus error.
>
> 0  lex_scan (zendlval=0xb6d2ce38) at /build/buildd/php5-5.4.6/Zend/zend_language_scanner.c:2260
>
> Thread 1 (Thread 0xb7485700 (LWP 588)):
>
> 0  lex_scan (zendlval=0xb6d2ce38) at /build/buildd/php5-5.4.6/Zend/zend_language_scanner.c:2260

So perhaps it's something to do with parsing? I know little about php internals however, so am uncertain. What might be causing this?

Comment: looks like either apache or php are broken, reinstall them and tell us if the error still occurs

Comment: it could even be a hardware issue.

Comment: @Soundz this occurs with both apache/mod_php and nginx/php_fpm, and with multiple versions of php, with with and without APC installed. Those combinations were all tested on the same instance so will try a fresh one and test on that...

Comment: having our share of this problem... 14.04/php55, 15.10/php56 - each time reproducible via vbox, but not having any problems on prod so far (amazon-linux with php56)